# OpenGL: changing texture coordinates on the fly

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, rendering, shader

I am currently trying to render the value of an integer using a bitmap (think scoreboard for invaders) but I'm having trouble changing texture coordinates while the game is running.

I link the shader and data like so:

```
GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
```

And in my shaders I do the following:
Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 mvp;

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;


void main() {
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position =  mvp * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0) ;
}
```

FragmentShader:

```
#version 150 core
in vec2 Texcoord;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
    outColor = texture2D(tex, Texcoord);
}
```

How would I change this code/implement a function to be able to change the texcoord variable?

Comment: Make a function to generate mesh that has the UV coordinates set in the right position. It's not a walk in the park, but it's not too hard.

Comment: @BWG I'm not quite sure what you mean with "UV coordinates set in the right position". To clarify, I manage to render a letter/digit initially, but I'm using a texture atlas to change the letter/digit by changing the texture coordinates.

Comment: When you say you "link the shader and data like so", you shouldn't be doing that. You only need to set up the shader once, but you need to update the data for your mesh every time you draw a new character. Or you could pass the shader your integer, and generate the texture coordinates there.

Comment: @BWG Right, I get that, thanks! Would that mean I have to change the variable types to something like layout qualifiers? How would I change/access these when I want to?

Comment: I personally use layout qualifiers, but I'm using OpenGL 3.3. I'll write you a more in depth answer.

Comment: @BWG Oh man thanks so much! OpenGL version is still changeable so don't feel limited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to modify the texture coordinates frequently, but the other vertex attributes remain unchanged, it can be beneficial to keep the texture coordinates in a separate VBO. While it's generally preferable to use interleaved attributes, this is one case where that's not necessarily the most efficient solution.

So you would have two VBOs, one for the positions, and one for the texture coordinates. Your setup code will look something like this:

```
GLuint vboIds[2];
glGenBuffers(2, vboIds);

// Load positions.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Load texture coordinates.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texCoords), texCoords, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Note the different last argument to `glBufferData()`, which is a usage hint. `GL_STATIC_DRAW` suggests to the OpenGL implementation that the data will not be modified on a regular basis, while `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` suggests that it will be modified frequently.

Then, anytime your texture data changes, you can modify it with `glBufferSubData()`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIds[1]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(texCoords), texCoords);
```

Of course if only part of them change, you would only make the call for the part that changes.

You did not specify how exactly the texture coordinates change. If it's just something like a simple transformation, it would be much more efficient to apply that transformation in the shader code, instead of modifying the original texture coordinates.

For example, say you only wanted to shift the texture coordinates. You could have a uniform variable for the shift in your vertex shader, and then add it to the incoming texture coordinate attribute:

```
uniform vec2 TexCoordShift;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 FragTexCoord;
...
    FragTexCoord = TexCoord + TexCoordShift;
```

and then in your C++ code:

```
// Once during setup, after linking program.
TexCoordShiftLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "TexCoordShift");

// To change transformation, after glUseProgram(), before glDraw*().
glUniform2f(TexCoordShiftLoc, xShift, yShift);
```

Comment: My fault I didn't mention that, but that is indeed the case. Would you mind showing me how to perform such a translation? My guess is another shader variable for the offset, but I don't know how to change it when I want to other than your method above.

Comment: I added to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

So I make no promises on the efficiency of this technique, but it's what I do and I'll be damned if text rendering is what slows down my program.

I have a dedicated class to store mesh, which consists of a few vectors of data, and a few `GLuint`s to store pointers to my uploaded data. I upload data to openGL like this:

```
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3) * data.position.size(), &data.position[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3) * data.normal.size(), &data.normal[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec2) * data.uv.size(), &data.uv[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index);
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * data.index.size(), &data.index[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Then, to draw it I go like this:

```
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionBinding);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, position);
        glVertexAttribPointer(positionBinding, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalBinding);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal);
        glVertexAttribPointer(normalBinding, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, NULL);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvBinding);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uv);
        glVertexAttribPointer(uvBinding, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionBinding);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalBinding);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(uvBinding);
```

This setup is designed for a full fledged 3D engine, so you can definitely tone it down a little. Basically, I have 4 buffers, position, uv, normal, and index. You probably only need the first two, so just ignore the others.

Anyway, each time I want to draw some text, I upload my data using the first code chunk I showed, then draw it using the second chunk. It works pretty well, and it's very elegant. This is my code to draw text using it:

```
vbo(genTextMesh("some string")).draw(); //vbo is my mesh containing class
```

I hope this helps, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Well it's late now so I'm going to sleep. I'll have a shot at it tomorrow. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I use a uniform `vec2` to pass the texture offset into the vertex shader.

I am not sure how efficient that is, but if your texture coordinates are the same shape, and just moved around, then this is an option.

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform vec2 texOffset;

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 Texcoord;


void main() {
    Texcoord = texcoord + texOffset;
    gl_Position =  mvp * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0) ;
}
```